# How to put custom HTML in changeview of django's admin?

Tags: django-admin

When I describe admin options for a model it's possible to put any method in 'list_display' then we can add 'allow_tags=True' and get HTML. Is there any same options but for 'changeview' form?
I can change template for the form but there is some calculation which returns HTML, so It's not good idea to put them all to a template.

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__','render_html')
```

render_html is a method of model, it works in listview, Putting it to 'fields' doesn't work.

Comment: what kind of calculations? you can always use javascript (in the template), AJAX to get data from the server etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack but it should work.

```
 class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):        
     def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
         context['adminform'].form.fields['somefield'].helptext= self.colored_name()
         return super(OrderAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs) 
     def colored_name(self):
         return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s %s</span>' % (self.color_code, self.first_name, self.last_name)
     colored_name.allow_tags = True
```